# java stream nested objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an object as follows and a list as per the object Type:

```
public class A{
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private List<A> child = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

What I want to do is flatten the list and make a list of Object A together with its children;

Currently I am doing in three separate statements as per below:

```
List<A> ChildElements = map.values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(entry -> entry.getChild().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<A> RootElements = map.values()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<A> elements = Stream.concat(ChildElements.stream(),RootElements.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I wanted to know if the above can be refactored in one statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want it all in one statement?

Comment: @Turing85 just for my knowledge and see if it can be written in lesser number of lines of codes.

Comment: `map.values().stream().flatMap(entry -> { final ArraryList<A> result = new ArrayList>(entry.getChild().stream())); result.add(entry); return result.stream(); }).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to concat streams immediately in the `flatMap`:

```
List<A> flattened = map.values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(root -> Stream.concat(
            Stream.of(root),
            root.getChildren().stream()
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, initial implementation provides another order of the elements in the results:

```
initial: child11, child12,... child1N1, child21,... child2N2, ...childMNm, root1,... rootM
flattened: root1, child11,... child1N1,... rootM, childM1... childMNm
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be like following:

```java
map.values()
  .stream()
  .flatMap(entry -> {
    Stream<A> entryStream = Stream.of(entry);
    Stream<A> childStream = entry.getChild().stream();
    return Stream.concat(entryStream, childStream);
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```